# How to aggregate multiple columns and output as rows?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using pyspark, and I have data like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |

My desired output is:

| col | sum |
| --- | --- |
| col1 | 4 |
| col2 | 2 |
| col3 | 1 |

My first thought was to put the column names in a list, loop through it, and each time sum that column and union the results to a new df.

Then I thought, maybe it's possible to do multiple aggregations, e.g.:

`df.agg(sum('col1), sum('col2))`

... and then figure out a way to unpivot.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easier way as far as I know. You can unpivot it after aggregating, either by first converting it to a Pandas dataframe and then invoking `transpose` on it or creating a map and then exploding the map to get the result as `col` and `sum` column.

```py
# Assuming initial dataframe is df
aggDF = df.agg(*[F.sum(F.col(col_name)).alias(col_name) for col_name in df.columns])

# Using pandas
aggDF.toPandas().transpose().reset_index().rename({'index' : 'col', 0: 'sum'}, axis=1)

# Going spark all the way
aggDF.withColumn("col", F.create_map([e for col in aggDF.columns for e in (F.lit(col), F.col(col))])).selectExpr("explode(col) as (col, sum)").show()

# Both return
"""
+----+---+
| col|sum|
+----+---+
|col1|  4|
|col2|  2|
|col3|  1|
+----+---+
"""
```

This works for more than 3 columns, if required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stack` SQL function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#stack) to unpivot a dataframe, as described [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/how-to-pivot-table-and-unpivot-a-spark-dataframe/). So your code would become, with `input` as your input dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output = input.agg(
  F.sum("col1").alias("col1"),
  F.sum("col2").alias("col2"),
  F.sum("col3").alias("col3")
).select(
  F.expr("stack(3, 'col1', col1, 'col2', col2, 'col3', col3) as (col,sum)")
)
```

If you have the following `input` dataframe:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|1   |0   |1   |
|1   |1   |0   |
|1   |1   |0   |
|1   |0   |0   |
+----+----+----+
```

You will get the following `output` dataframe:

```
+----+---+
|col |sum|
+----+---+
|col1|4  |
|col2|2  |
|col3|1  |
+----+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first sum each column:

```
// input
val df = List((1,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,0)).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
df.show

// sum each column
val sums = df.agg(sum("coL1").as("col1"), sum("col2").as("col2"), 
sum("col3").as("col3"))
sums.show 

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   4|   2|   1|
+----+----+----+
```

This gives you a DS with one row, and 3 columns. Which you can easily collect. And if that's what you want, create a new dataset with:

```
val sumRow = sums.first

val sumDS = List("col1" -> sumRow.getAs[Long]("col1"), "col2" -> 
sumRow.getAs[Long]("col2"), "col3" -> sumRow.getAs[Long]("col3")).toDF("col", "sum")
sumDS.show

+----+---+
| col|sum|
+----+---+
|col1|  4|
|col2|  2|
|col3|  1|
+----+---+
```